# problem with opneing omni.ja file

Tags: java

How to open a .ja file. Do I need any app for it?
e.g : /usr/lib/thunderbird/omni.ja .
its a thunderbird archive file and archive manager shows an "archive type not supported" error.

Answer (score 0):

```
unzip omni.ja
```

works.

---

```
:/usr/lib/firefox/tmp$ sudo unzip omni.ja
:/usr/lib/firefox/tmp$ ls 
chrome           components  greprefs.js  jssubloader  omni.ja
chrome.manifest  defaults    jsloader     modules      res
:/usr/lib/firefox/tmp$
```

Comment: thanks but is there a way to have the files in the file manager?

Comment: what do you mean by that? you can examine the files from nautilus if you want to. By the way: there is no reason to need to extract these files from omni.ja. For anything inside this archive there is a command or setting to manipulate it.

Comment: How to open it in nautilus? There are directories in it and I have to change a single png file in one of those dirctories.